# Responsive navigation bar with Bootstrap 2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-2

I need to make a responsive navigation in Bootstrap 2 and I have some difficulties to implement this...

This is how the design looks on computer screens and on smaller screens, or mobile, I want it to be on a "Sort" dropdown, just like the Categories but with items "all","new","popular","unread" and "promoted"

[image]

And I also want to know if this could be done with divs, without using "navbar" class

Quick example:

HTML:

```
<div class="sort">
    <div class="inline all"v>All</div>
    <div class="inline new">New</div>
    <div class="inline popular">Popular</div>
    <div class="inline unread">Unread</div>
    <div class="inline promoted">Promoted</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inline {
    display:inline;
}
.new { 
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.unread {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: If possible make a demo, rather than attaching an image. You'll probably get a quicker reply.

Comment: Even after trying to import Bootstrap 2, your demo is missing all its native classes. Can you update please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tsg67uej/ it is possible to make those divs responsive so that on mobile devices they're will be in a dropdown?

Comment: Updated your fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ozo8agj5/1/)
Your issue is that you didn't implement any of the Bootstrap 2 classes.

Comment: Thanks! This answered my question. It is possible to make the "Brand" text appear only on smaller screens? I mean it shouldn't appear on larger screens